# Using loops to go through string and check char as a dict key

Tags: string, swift, loops, dictionary

so I want to kind of build a "Decrypter", I have a dictionary with the keys being the symbol, and the value the respective value for the symbol, then I have this string that the code is suppose to look into, the translate will be saved in a other string, in this case called output. This is the way I did the loop part, but is not working:

```
var outputText = " "

for character in textForScan{
    for key in gematriaToLetters{
        if (gematriaToLetters.keys == textForScan[character]){
            outputText.insert(gematriaToLetters.values, atIndex: outputText.endIndex)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which types do the variables `textForScan` and `gematriaToLetters` have?

Comment: Is it `Dictionary<String, String>` or `Dictionary<Character, Character>`?

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider using `map`:

```
let outputText = "".join(map(textForScan) { gematriaToLetters[String($0)] ?? String($0) })
```

If you don't specify a specific letter in the dictionary it returns the current letter without "converting".

Comment: Wow, what a cool feature, but does it have a char limit? i don't think it is translating everything

Comment: @Skal in this case you will always have the same character count. Small example:  `let gematriaToLetters = ["s": "n"]; let textForScan = "mass"; let outputText = "mann";` Non specified characters stay the same.

Comment: it's because my text kind of have 17 thousand chars, and I think it doesn't show all up

Comment: @Skal I don't know why but you can check it using `count(outputText)` which returns the character count.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
for aCharacter in textForScan {
    let newChar = gematrialToLetters["\(aCharacter)"]
    outputText += newChar
}
print(outputText)
```

Comment: No. Exemple i have the following textForScan: `"% ^*"` .Them for the first char it should check the dictionary `gematriaToLetters` , for the key `%` and  assign the value to the `outputText`

Comment: That's what the code I provided should do. Does it not?

Comment: it doesn't don't know why

Comment: If you debug after my new edit, what is the value of newChar?

Comment: it says it cannot subscript a value of <string: string> to char

Comment: Now it says it cannot invoke append to a type of String?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87537/discussion-between-mikeatnobel-and-skal).